# ¿Como puedo hacer que al pasar el mouse por encima del div aplique los nuevos efectos a la "caja" y al texto a la vez?

Tags: css

Al pasar el mouse donde pone "acceso usuarios" (la caja digamos, el div, no el texto) se ilumina y esta correcto pero intento que se aplique los efectos que le puse al texto a la vez (si pasas el mouse por encima del texto de "acceso usuarios" verás que sale una linea debajo de color y el texto aumenta de tamaño. He intentando aplicar los efectos del hover del texto al div y no me funciona.

Aquí el código, pasen el mouse donde acceso usuarios para ver el problema:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

/* ----------------HEADER------------------- */

header {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0d8c77;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #010b3d;
  border-right: 4px solid #010b3d;
}

.divlogoimg {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.logoimg {
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.header-usuarios,
.header-autonomos,
.header-empresas {
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #009b81;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #010b3d;
  text-align: center;
}


.header-usuarios-text,
.header-autonomos-text,
.header-empresas-text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

/*effects*/
.span-header-usuarios-text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0), rgba(1, 1, 1, 0)),
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgb(68, 2, 221),
      rgba(152, 215, 194, 1),
      rgb(63, 230, 194)
    );
  background-size: 100% 0.1em, 0 0.3em;
  background-position: 100% 100%, 0 115%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 350ms;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.span-header-usuarios-text:hover,
.span-header-usuarios-text:focus {
  background-size: 0 0.1em, 100% 0.3em;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 2s;
  transition: background-size 350ms;
}

.header-usuarios:hover,
.header-usuarios:focus {
  background-color: rgb(13, 211, 158);
}

/* ----------------BODY------------------- */

body {
  background-color: #006d5b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="header-logo">
        <div class="divlogoimg">
          <img class="logoimg" src="/img/logoedit.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-usuarios">
        <div class="header-usuarios-text"><span class="span-header-usuarios-text">ACCESO USUARIOS</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-autonomos">
        <div class="header-autonomos-text"><span class="span-header-autonomos-text">ACCESO AUTONOMOS</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-empresas">
        <div class="header-empresas-text"><span class="span-header-empresas-text">ACCESO EMPRESAS</span></div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El codigo no lo enlazamos en las preguntas, lo incluimos en ellas.  Para que lo veas acabo de editar tu pregunta y lo he agregado mediante la adición de un snippet. Puedes llevarte [votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/3883#3883) si usas enlaces a tu código

Answer (score 0):

¿Te refieres a dejarlo así?  Ejecuta y prueba el código siguiente:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

/* ----------------HEADER------------------- */

header {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0d8c77;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #010b3d;
  border-right: 4px solid #010b3d;
}

.divlogoimg {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.logoimg {
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.header-usuarios,
.header-autonomos,
.header-empresas {
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #009b81;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #010b3d;
  text-align: center;
}


.header-usuarios-text,
.header-autonomos-text,
.header-empresas-text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

/*effects*/
.span-header-usuarios-text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0), rgba(1, 1, 1, 0)),
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgb(68, 2, 221),
      rgba(152, 215, 194, 1),
      rgb(63, 230, 194)
    );
  background-size: 100% 0.1em, 0 0.3em;
  background-position: 100% 100%, 0 115%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 350ms;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.header-usuarios:hover
.span-header-usuarios-text {
  background-size: 0 0.1em, 100% 0.3em;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 2s;
  transition: background-size 350ms;
}

.header-usuarios:hover,
.header-usuarios:focus {
  background-color: rgb(13, 211, 158);
}

/* ----------------BODY------------------- */

body {
  background-color: #006d5b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="header-logo">
        <div class="divlogoimg">
          <img class="logoimg" src="/img/logoedit.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-usuarios">
        <div class="header-usuarios-text"><span class="span-header-usuarios-text">ACCESO USUARIOS</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-autonomos">
        <div class="header-autonomos-text"><span class="span-header-autonomos-text">ACCESO AUTONOMOS</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-empresas">
        <div class="header-empresas-text"><span class="span-header-empresas-text">ACCESO EMPRESAS</span></div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```